# Python: str.split() - is it possible to only specify the "limit" parameter?

Tags: python, string

I want to split a string on **whitespaces (default behavior)**, but I want it to split it only once - I.e. I want it to return an array with 2 items at most.

If it is not possible - i.e. if for specifying the limit I have to also specify the pattern - could you please tell how to specify the default one?

Comment: This is clearly stated in the docs; ``None`` is the default behaviour.

Comment: By the way, I've noticed that in Python3 they added a keyword "maxsplit"

Comment: `maxsplit` can be found in `str.split` as far back as Python 2.0.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary: Sure, Py2 `str.split()` can take a `maxsplit` arg, but it's a positional arg, not a keyword arg, so to use  `maxsplit` with the default splitting in Py2 you must specify `None` for the separator.

Comment: Yes. `'a  b     c'.split(maxsplit=1)` -> `['a', 'b     c']`

Comment: @Boris, thanks. This question was asked 6 years ago, when Python 2 was still very popular. As mentioned in the answers to this question, in Python 2, the first parameter had to be specified, such that solution was to use `None` as the first parameter, or do as you mentioned in Python 3.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

This works:

```
>>> 'a b c'.split(None, 1)
['a', 'b c']
```

The docstring:

> S.split(sep=None, maxsplit=-1) -> list of strings
>
> Return a list of the words in S, using sep as the
>   delimiter string.  If maxsplit is given, at most maxsplit
>   splits are done. If sep is not specified or is None, any
>   whitespace string is a separator and empty strings are
>   removed from the result.

You should explore at the interactive prompt:

```
>>> help('a'.split)
```

In IPython just use a question mark:

```
In [1]:  s = 'a'
In [2]:  s.split?
```

I would suggest using [IPython](http://ipython.org/) and especially the Notebook. This makes this kind of exploration much more convenient.

Answer (score 5):

If you specify `None` as a separator, you'll get the default behavior:

```
str.split(None, maxsplit)
```

> S.split([sep [,maxsplit]]) -> list of strings
>
> Return a list of the words in the string S, using sep as the
>   delimiter string.  If maxsplit is given, at most maxsplit
>   splits are done. If sep is not specified or is None, any
>   whitespace string is a separator and empty strings are removed
>   from the result.

Answer (score 5):

## Split string on consecutive whitespace<sup>†</sup> at most *maxsplit* times<sup>††</sup>

<sup>†</sup> Resulting list will contain *no* leading or trailing empty strings (`""`) if the string has leading or trailing whitespace

<sup>††</sup> Splits are made left to right. To split the other way (right to left), use the `str.rsplit()` method (requires Python 2.4+)

---

### Python 2

> #### `str.split(sep[, maxsplit]])`
>
> Use `str.split(None, maxsplit)`
>
> **Note**:
>   Specifying `sep` as `None` **≝** not specifying *`sep`*
>
> `str.split(None, -1)` **≝** `str.split()` **≝** `str.split(None)`

---

### Python 3

> #### `str.split(sep=None, maxsplit=-1)`
>
> Option A: Stick with positional arguments (Python 2 option): `str.split(None, maxsplit)`
>
> ```
> >>> ' 4 2 0 '.split(None, 420)
> ['4', '2', '0']
> ```
>
> Option B (personal preference, using keyword arguments): `str.split(maxsplit=maxsplit)`
>
> ```
> >>> ' 4 2 0 '.split(maxsplit=420)` 
> ['4', '2', '0']
> ```