# Split a list up to a maximum number of elements

Tags: python, arrays

I was wondering if someone could help me with the following problem: I have a text file that I split into rows and columns. The text file contains a variable amount of columns, however I would like to split each row into seven columns, no more, no less. To do that, I want to through everything after the sixth column into a single column.

Example code:

```
import numpy as np

rot = ['6697 1100.0   90.0    0.0    0.0  6609 !',                                                                                                                         

'701  0.0   0.0    83.9   1.5    000 !AFR-AHS IndHS-AFR']

for i in range(len(rot)):
    rot[i]=rot[i].split()
```

Here, the array 'rot' contains 7 entries in the first row (the ! counts as a separate entry) and 8 in the second row. In both cases, everything after and including the ! should be grouped in the same column.

Many thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: str.split() - is it possible to only specify the "limit" parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30437566/python-str-split-is-it-possible-to-only-specify-the-limit-parameter)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are *almost* there.  `split` takes (as its second argument) the maximum number of splits to do.

https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#str.split

```
rot = ['6697 1100.0   90.0    0.0    0.0  6609 !',
'701  0.0   0.0    83.9   1.5    000 !AFR-AHS IndHS-AFR']

for i in range(len(rot)):
    rot[i]=rot[i].split(maxsplit=6)
```

Note:  You want six splits, which results in seven columns.  You'll need to do some extra processing if the text can have fewer than seven columns though.