# Strange behavior of (python) str.split when using the default sep value (None)

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, split

Does anyone have a clear way to explain the rule regarding `str.split(sep=None)`? The Docstring provides some explanation but not enough to understand the following behaviors

```
>>> s = '\n Hello\t World\nOpps\t '
>>> print(s.split()) #by default sep = None
['Hello', 'World', 'Opps']
>>> print(s.split(maxsplit = 1))
['Hello', 'World\nOpps\t ']
```

- The first print seems reasonable since it splits whenever whitespace appears, and then dump all the empty strings.
- The second one is a bit harder to understanding: if it only splits once, then it should condiser the 1st '\n' as the delimiter and results in an empty string `''` (which should be dumped next) and `' Hello World\nOpps\t'`.

Thank you in advance for any consistent and logical explanation you may provide.

PS: I have included the Docstring in below, and I am aware of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30437566/5147567), and [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56108440/5147567) there offers some help but a clear rule with official source is still missing. Without official source explanation, a rule is just something for users to memorize without understanding.

> sep
> The delimiter according which to split the string.
> None (the default value) means split according to any whitespace,
> and discard empty strings from the result.

Answer (score 1):

Since the overflow [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [this](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) stackoverflow blog post stated that it is encouraged to answer one's own question, I am posting a possible interpretation I can think of (edited after seeing the answer provided by [@juanpa-arrivillaga](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5014455/) and reading the official doc): when `sep=None`, the special rule for `str.split` is as follows.

1. Attempt to remove all the leading whitespace(s)
2. As a convention, runs of consecutive whitespace are regarded as a single separator according to the [official doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split).
3. Apply the split once at a time using the convention of item 1 until maxsplit is reached.
4. Disregard any empty string in the resulted list.
   An interesting observation is that even when `maxsplit=0`, python still conducts item 1, as illustrated by the following example.

```
>>> s = '\n Hello\t World\nOpps\t '
>>> print(s.split(maxsplit = 0))
['Hello\t World\nOpps\t ']
>>> print(s.split(maxsplit = 1))
['Hello', 'World\nOpps\t ']
>>> print(s.split(maxsplit = 2))
['Hello', 'World', 'Opps\t ']
>>> print(s.split(maxsplit = 3))
['Hello', 'World', 'Opps']
```

Answer (score 1):

You should look at the [official docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split), where this is explained in detail:

> If `sep` is not specified or is `None`, a different splitting
> algorithm is applied: **runs of consecutive whitespace are regarded as
> a single separator**, and the result will contain no empty strings at
> the start or end if the string has leading or trailing whitespace.
> Consequently, splitting an empty string or a string consisting of just
> whitespace with a None separator returns `[]`.

Bold emphasis added by me.

However, this does leave ambiguity regarding what a "split" is in the case of `sep=None, maxsplit=some_positive_number). But apparently, the leading and trailing whitespace acts, at least conceptually, as if it simply wasn't there. But notice:

```
>>> "   a   b c ".split(maxsplit=1)
['a', 'b c ']
```

So it isn't actually removed.

Comment: Oh, thanks pointing to the official docs for that. I thought checking the Docstring was sufficient. Thank you. Should I delete this question then?

Comment: @AlexFeng nah, this question is fine.

Comment: I think my guess (in my own answer) matches Python's interpretation: runs of consecutive whitespace are regarded as a single separator, and leading whitespaces are removed first (although the official doc does not explicitly mentioned this). Thank you for helping